# Conditional Formatting on cells with the result of a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of domains that my company owns. In the control panel it doesn't show an expiration date but we always choose a two year option on the domain.

What I have figured out is how to calculate how many days are left till renewal. But what I can't figure out is how to apply a 3 color coded conditional formatting on the cells that return the number days till renewal.

Example:

Here is the formula to find the number of days left.

=DATEVALUE("16-July-2016")-TODAY()&""

So I am trying to get numbers from:

- 0-100 a red color
- 101-400 a yellow color
- 401-730 a green color

I keep trying to apply it to the cells with that show the days left, but it won't show any color.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Depending on the version of excel you are using, you should be able to just right click the cell(s) you want and select "conditional formatting". Set a rule for each condition you want.

http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel

Comment: I was said that this is not what OP asked ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With &"" at the end of your formula, the result outputs as TEXT, and Conditional Formatting is trying to evaluate numbers. Set your formula to just `=DATEVALUE("16-July-2016")-TODAY()` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: And format those cells as numbers because otherwise it will show you dates.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. I didn't even think about formatting the cell itself for number.... ugh... the little things. Thank you very much for your help! Both Jorge and Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe three separate rules, applied to whichever column your values (excluding `&""`) are in (here assumed to be `A`):

[image: SO24873783 example]

Answer (score -1):

In Excel, Home -> Conditional Formatting.
See this [introduction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx) on Conditional Formatting.